# Macro not selecting range for comment change in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to write a macro for Excel 2010 that will take a user selection of a cell or range of merged cells and unbold the comment and add a pattern.

```
Sub commentstripe()
'
' commentstripe Macro
'
'
    Dim myRange As Range
    Set myRange = Range(Selection.Address)
    myRange.Comment.Shape.TextFrame.Characters.Font.Bold = False
    With myRange.Interior
        .Pattern = xlLightUp
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
End Sub
```

It seems to be hanging on the myRange.comment line but I can't seem to figure out why. I'm running it from a shortcut, Ctrl+Shift+A. Any advice would be appreciated.

Regards,
Sandy

Comment: It did in the Visual Basic Editor (in the pop-up box).

Comment: I'm getting Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set. In playing around with it some more, it works on single cells but not a single cell made of merged cells.

Comment: Or it can be that the cell has no comment.See below for a better way of handling comments:

Sub CommentAdd()
    Dim cmt As Comment
    Dim cmtText As String
    
    Set cmt = ActiveCell.Comment

    If cmt Is Nothing Then
        Set cmt = ActiveCell.AddComment
    Else
        'do nothing
    End If

With cmt.Shape.TextFrame
    .Characters.Font.FontStyle.Bold = False
End With

Comment: Yea Andres may be right. Not sure how comments work with merged cells. And how is user selecting cells? Because selecting any range without a comment will break. Can you loop through all comments instead?

Comment: The user is selecting a cell or merged cell by clicking on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see why it would hang... except for the fact that if there's no comment in the cell, it will throw an error.
Also, if this is a new workbook, and you just save it, it will throw a warning saying this is an excel file, not a macro-enabled excel file. Just for you to know.

I commented the save line and everything worked perfectly.

EDIT: See if this works

```
Sub commentstripe()

Dim myRange As Range
Set myRange = Selection
myRange.Cells(1, 1).Comment.Shape.TextFrame.Characters.Font.Bold = False
With myRange.Interior
    .Pattern = xlLightUp
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With
ActiveWorkbook.Save
End Sub
```

Comment: It seems to be working with single cells but not a single cell made of merged cells. The single cells are working both with and without the save at the end. Edited: It has a comment in both types of cells.

Comment: I just tried an update, please see the edit to my answer.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't seem to work on either the single cells or merged cells. It gives Run-time error '424': Object required.

Comment: That's correct, my bad. The right one is myRange.Cells